# Extract IP Addresses from Large File into Groups of One Hundred and Place Inside Two-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have a large file containing around 2,600 IPs addresses, one per line including the line feed character:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\n
YY.YYY.YY.YYY\n
ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ\n
```

I want to be able to extract all the IPs into a two dimensional array (stripping the `\n`. The first element of the array would be an array of the first one hundred IPs, the second element of the array, would be another list, but now containing the second batch of one hundred IPs from the file.

Any pointers on how I could accomplish that would be very much appreciated.